# Swift UIAlertController showing custom message

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a ViewController class thats only purpose is to display an alert message with a custom message and title that is passes in through a custom init message. This is done as soon as the view appears, in viewDidLoad. My problem however is that when it comes to this view it pops up and is stuck in this view forever, instead of just putting the view over the other. I am not sure how to fix this. Here is the code for my alertVC class

```
import UIKit

class AlertVC: UIViewController {

  var myMessage: String?
  var myTitle: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: myTitle, message: myMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
        (action: UIAlertAction) in print("Youve pressed OK Button")
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  convenience init(title: String, message: String){
    self.init()
    self.myTitle = title
    self.myMessage = message
  }
}
```

This is the code for how I create an object for this and try and show it.

```
let alert = AlertVC(title: "Error", message: "error")
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Any help is appreciated, leave a comment if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: If `AlertVC`'s only purpose is to display the `UIAlertController`, why don't you just present the `UIAlertController` on your previous `ViewController`?

Comment: I was trying to create a way to use the alert view in any class by creating an object oriented way for it. I have about 5 classes that may need it, but I would prefer an abstract way of doing things instead of just hard coding it in every time.

Comment: You're calling it in the `viewdidappear()` method. Call it in the `viewdidload()`.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand.  I have edited my answer.  :)

Comment: Please check this global UIAlertController extension:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60414319/8201581

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why not simply an `extension`?

```
extension UIViewController {

  func presentAlert(withTitle title: String, message : String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
        print("You've pressed OK Button")
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

and call it with

```
presentAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: "error")
```

in any `UIViewController` class

Comment: Does it matter where I put this extension? As in should it go below my AlertVC class? I have not used extensions much before @vadian

Comment: You can put it everywhere on the top level of a file (outside any other class, struct, enum). I'm using extensions very much in a extra file `Extensions`

Comment: Great. Okey this good solution but if I want to add UITextFiled for input. How do i handle text input?

Comment: @ErkamKUCET Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Uialertcontroller+text+field)

Answer (score 0):

If `AlertVC`'s only purpose is to display the `UIAlertController`, why don't you just present the `UIAlertController` on your previous `ViewController`?

So where you have written this:

```
let alert = AlertVC(title: "Error", message: "error")
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Replace it with:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: myTitle, message: myMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
    (action: UIAlertAction) in print("Youve pressed OK Button")
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT**: After reading your comment, I understand that you want to avoid typing the same code multiple times.  I've done some quick research and it seems you [shouldn't subclass UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/), so perhaps an extension may be useful?   Something like:

```
extension UIAlertController{
    class func customAlertController(title : String, message : String) -> UIAlertController{
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            (action: UIAlertAction) in print("Youve pressed OK Button")
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        return alertController
    }
}
```

Then replace:

```
let alert = AlertVC(title: "Error", message: "error")
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController.customAlertController("Error!", message: "error")
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true) {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand what is happening with this :)

Answer (score 0):

**@vadian's answer in Swift 3 with completion handler added to alert controller dismiss.**

```
extension UIViewController {

    func presentAlertWithTitle(title: String, message : String, onDismiss: SimpleCompletionBlock? = nil)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            (action: UIAlertAction) in print("Youve pressed OK Button")

            onDismiss?()
        }

        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```